# How write query to fetch json attibute inside nested JSON array object

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures

I have tables like like

1. UserDetails which contains UserID,FirstName,LastName and Email
2. JSONDetails which contains JSON_ID,JSON,UserID
3. Templates which contains Template_ID,TemplateName,Tag

Sample JSON which I am Storing in JSONDetails table

```
 [{
        "moduleid": "3",
        "ischecked": true,
        "activity": [{
            "tag": "Project",
            "text": "All Project related activites email",
            "ischecked": false,
            "emailsettingvalue": "NoEmail"
        }, {
            "tag": "Contacts",
            "text": "All Contact related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }, {
            "tag": "RFI",
            "text": "All RFI related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }, {
            "tag": "Ticket",
            "text": "All Ticket related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }]
    }, {
        "moduleid": "2",
        "ischecked": true,
        "activity": [{
            "tag": "Project",
            "text": "All Project related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }, {
            "tag": "Contacts",
            "text": "All Contact related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }, {
            "tag": "RFI",
            "text": "All RFI related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }, {
            "tag": "Ticket",
            "text": "All Ticket related activites email",
            "ischecked": true,
            "emailsettingvalue": "Instant"
        }]
    }]
```

I have Input Email,moduleid and TemplateName how do I write SP query to get emailsetting value based on my input values.

my thinking as below

- get tag using TemplateName storing it in a variable
- JOIN UserDetails to JSONDetails get JSON
- then extract emailsetting value using moduleid and tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json_extract to find the values inside the json.

Here's a fiddle based on your data.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a167b9ecb738993f3ef972ef77b8f2a9

Comment: select JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.activity[*].emailsettingvalue")
from json_sample where JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.tag") = 'Ticket' and
JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.moduleid") = "2";   is not working y

Comment: See this link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95677a84c83e6889b70794c67319a9ca

This is the correct query:

`select
  JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.activity[*].emailsettingvalue")
from
  json_sample
where
  JSON_CONTAINS(content, '{"tag": "Ticket"}', "$.activity")
  and JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.moduleid") = "2";`

Comment: This input should fetch only one email setting value but your query returning 4

Comment: Fixed a typo in the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a167b9ecb738993f3ef972ef77b8f2a9 Since the object with module id 2 matches both checks, the entire document gets selected.

Comment: For your case, you want to extract the nested object and not the overall json object, based on the constraint. Sorry. I don't know.

Comment: This should fetch only one email setting value why are we getting 4

Comment: We are getting 4 because the matching top level document has 4 activities, each with an emailSetting key.

Comment: thats why we are passing tag value we need to get email setting value based on the moduleid and tag.Can you create user details and template details so that i can understand full query

Comment: There are 2 pieces in the select statement we're using. 1 is the selection part. The other is the condition part. The condition part requires a json row to have module id = 2 and one of its tags to have {tag = ticket}. The row is picked up. Since we're extracting all the emailsettingvalue values from the complete document, we get 4 of them.

Is it possible for you to get the tag value from inside your application code after doing the additional check in the application layer?